# JETTY: Embedded JSP inside its jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty

I'm using Jetty 8.0. to create a simple web server (html/json/png) inside my java application.

I added an handler to use jsp pages positioned inside a package (as mentioned here:  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty):

```
        String WEBAPPDIR = "com/econorma/jsp/resources";
        String CONTEXTPATH = "/jsp";

        URL warUrl = WebApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPPDIR);
        final String warUrlString = warUrl.toExternalForm();
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(warUrlString, CONTEXTPATH);
```

I tested this code in Eclipse without any problems: html and jsp both work.

[image]

My problem come when I run my jar deployed. I get NULL POINTER exception in the getClassLoader line.

I try to put the slash at the end of WEBAPPDIR as mentioned in one StackOverflow post but, also if I solve the null pointer exception, I can't me it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two problems for my embedded jetty and jsp:

1-Missing code before calling my webClass:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "true");
```

2-The Eclipse export to prepare the jar: I used the EXTRACT method and non the PACKAGE one and so it wasn't possibile to find jsp inside the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the updated codes of jsp and html files back into the jar to work properly.
The local jsp pages in the package `com.econorma.ui.resources` will be available only for development process and when you export your project as a war file. The jars will not have the changes that you made in jsp pages which you had in `com.econorma.ui.resources`.

So you need to copy of jsp or html files from the package you created. And then put these files in the jar in the appropriate packages and update it.

Now you have to build your project again after installing the new jars files and restart your jetty server to see the changes and you should be able to run your server without errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: But is it possibile to have  jsp pages inside jar with jetty or not?

Comment: Maybe I have to create a configuration xml to let Jetty knows the correct jsp folder. Like in This examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128145/Run-Jetty-Web-Server-Within-Your-Application